# Cakephp find not working as expected

Tags: database, cakephp, find

I'm working on a small app to help learn cakephp 2.0. Its a simple task manager app.

## Tables

- users
- tasks
- tasktypes

I've a set up a foreign key in the tasks table called 'user_id'
As a task belongs to a user.

Now all I'm trying to do is display the tasks of a certain user and it wont work at all despite the sql query getting correct results when I tested it any help would be great.

In my taskscontroller I've the method;

```
//show the tasks of the current user
public function mytasks(){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Gerrys TaskManager: Display Tasks');

    $this->Task->recursive = 0;         

    $tasks=$this->Task->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('username'=>'admin')));       

    $this->set('tasks', $this->paginate());     
}
```

I'm trying to find the tasks of the user 'admin' or the "realted tasks" what am I doing wrong?

I suspect the problem maybe to with my models;

```
usermodel

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Task' => array(
            'className' => 'Task',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
```

task model;

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Tasktype' => array(
        'className' => 'Tasktype',
        'foreignKey' => 'tasktype_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tasks that belong to a user, it's much simpler to do that in the UsersController. Of course you have to set User hasMany Task in your UserModel.

Now you can create a function, for example to view the User and it's Tasks by id:

```
public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }
```

The Tasks should now be available in your view by `$user['tasks']`. You have to pass the id in the url like: /path_to_your_app/users/view/**1**

You can always use `debug()` to see contents of an array or variable. To see what you've got add `<?php debug($user);?>` to your view.

You most likely want to list any tasks with a foreach in your view, very simple example::

```
foreach($user['Task'] as $task) {
    echo $task['field1'] . ": " . $task['fied2'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

of course you might want to display the tasks in tables or something.

A good starting point for learning cakePHP is the Blog-Tutorial:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial